MariaDB custom pluging for encryption
I have below C++ code for my custom encryption plugin and created a shared object (.so) file.
but while running the query in mariadb INSTALL PLUGIN JISA_Encryption_Plugin SONAME 'JISA_Enc_Plugin.so';, below error is coming

ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'JISA_Enc_Plugin.so' (errno: 8, API version for ENCRYPTION plugin JISA_Encryption_Plugin not supported by this version of the server)

I am using MariaDB version 10.6.
code:
#include <cstddef>      // for size_t
#include <map>          // for std::map
#include <cstring>      // for memcpy
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"  // Assuming you have this header
using json = nlohmann::json;
#include <iostream>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <typelib.h>
#include <mysql/plugin_ftparser.h>
#include <mysql/plugin_encryption.h>
#include <mysql/service_my_crypt.h>


struct KeyEntry {
   unsigned int id;
   unsigned char key[32];  // Example size, adjust as necessary
   unsigned int length;
};


std::map<unsigned int, KeyEntry> keys;
static char* filename;
static char* filekey;
static unsigned long encryption_algorithm;


static const char *encryption_algorithm_names[] = {
 "aes_cbc",
#ifdef HAVE_EncryptAes128Ctr
 "aes_ctr",
#endif
 0
};


static TYPELIB encryption_algorithm_typelib = {
 array_elements(encryption_algorithm_names)-1, "",
 encryption_algorithm_names, NULL
};


static MYSQL_SYSVAR_STR(filename, filename,
 PLUGIN_VAR_RQCMDARG | PLUGIN_VAR_READONLY,
 "Path and name of the key file.",
 NULL, NULL, "");


static MYSQL_SYSVAR_STR(filekey, filekey,
 PLUGIN_VAR_RQCMDARG | PLUGIN_VAR_READONLY,
 "Key to encrypt / decrypt the keyfile.",
 NULL, NULL, "");


#ifdef HAVE_EncryptAes128Ctr
#define RECOMMENDATION  ", aes_ctr is the recommended one"
#else
#define RECOMMENDATION  ""
#endif


static MYSQL_SYSVAR_ENUM(encryption_algorithm, encryption_algorithm,
 PLUGIN_VAR_RQCMDARG | PLUGIN_VAR_READONLY,
 "Encryption algorithm to use" RECOMMENDATION ".",
 NULL, NULL, 0, &encryption_algorithm_typelib);


static struct st_mysql_sys_var* settings[] = {
 MYSQL_SYSVAR(filename),
 MYSQL_SYSVAR(filekey),
 MYSQL_SYSVAR(encryption_algorithm),
 NULL
};


// Function to read the key file
void readKeyFile(const std::string& filename) {
   std::ifstream file(filename);
   if (!file.is_open()) {
       std::cerr << "Failed to open the file: " << filename << std::endl;
       return;
   }


   std::string line;
   while (std::getline(file, line)) {
       std::istringstream iss(line);
       std::string id_str, key_str;


       if (std::getline(iss, id_str, ';') && std::getline(iss, key_str)) {
           unsigned int id = std::stoi(id_str);


           if (key_str.length() != 64) { // Each byte is represented by 2 hex digits, 32 bytes * 2 = 64
               std::cerr << "Invalid key length for ID " << id << std::endl;
               continue;
           }


           KeyEntry entry;
           entry.id = id;
           entry.length = 32; // Fixed length in this example


           for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
               std::string byteString = key_str.substr(i * 2, 2);
               entry.key[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stoi(byteString, nullptr, 16));
           }


           keys[id] = entry;
       }
   }
}


// Function to get key from the keys map
static KeyEntry* getKey(unsigned int key_id) {
   auto it = keys.find(key_id);
   if (it == keys.end()) {
       return nullptr;
   }
   return &it->second;
}


// Function to get the latest version of the key
static unsigned int get_latest_key_version(unsigned int key_id) {
   return getKey(key_id) ? 1 : ENCRYPTION_KEY_VERSION_INVALID;
}


// Function to get the key from the key file
static unsigned int get_key(unsigned int key_id, unsigned int key_version, unsigned char* dstbuf, unsigned *buflen) {
   if (key_version != 1) {
       return ENCRYPTION_KEY_VERSION_INVALID;
   }


   KeyEntry* entry = getKey(key_id);


   if (entry == NULL) {
       return ENCRYPTION_KEY_VERSION_INVALID;
   }


   if (*buflen < entry->length) {
       *buflen = entry->length;
       return ENCRYPTION_KEY_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;
   }


   *buflen = entry->length;
   if (dstbuf) {
       memcpy(dstbuf, entry->key, entry->length);
   }


   return 0;
}


#ifndef HAVE_EncryptAes128Gcm
#ifndef HAVE_EncryptAes128Ctr
#define MY_AES_CTR MY_AES_CBC
#endif
#define MY_AES_GCM MY_AES_CTR
#endif


static inline enum my_aes_mode mode(int flags) {
 if (encryption_algorithm)
   if (flags & ENCRYPTION_FLAG_NOPAD)
     return MY_AES_CTR;
   else
     return MY_AES_GCM;
 else
   return MY_AES_CBC;
}


// Implement AES encryption functions using OpenSSL
int crypt_ctx_init(void *ctx, const unsigned char *key, unsigned int klen,
                     const unsigned char *iv, unsigned int ivlen, int flags,
                     unsigned int key_id, unsigned int key_version) {
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX *context = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX *)ctx;
   const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;


   switch (mode(flags)) {
       case MY_AES_CBC:
           cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc();
           break;
       case MY_AES_CTR:
           cipher = EVP_aes_256_ctr();
           break;
       default:
           return -1;
   }


   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(context);
   if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(context, cipher, NULL, key, iv) != 1) {
       return -1;
   }


   return 0;
}


int crypt_ctx_update(void *ctx, const unsigned char *src, unsigned int slen,
                       unsigned char *dst, unsigned int *dlen) {
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX *context = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX *)ctx;
   int len;


   if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(context, dst, &len, src, slen) != 1) {
       return -1;
   }


   *dlen = len;
   return 0;
}


int crypt_ctx_finish(void *ctx, unsigned char *dst, unsigned int *dlen) {
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX *context = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX *)ctx;
   int len;


   if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(context, dst, &len) != 1) {
       return -1;
   }


   *dlen = len;
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(context);
   return 0;
}


unsigned int encrypted_length(unsigned int slen, unsigned int key_id, unsigned int key_version) {
   switch (mode(0)) {
       case MY_AES_CBC:
           return slen + EVP_CIPHER_block_size(EVP_aes_256_cbc());
       case MY_AES_CTR:
           return slen; // CTR mode does not change the length
       default:
           return 0; // Unsupported mode
   }
}


unsigned int crypt_ctx_size(unsigned int key_id, unsigned int key_version) {
   return sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX*);
}


struct st_mariadb_encryption JISA_Enc_plugin = {
   MARIA_PLUGIN_INTERFACE_VERSION,
   get_latest_key_version,
   get_key,
   crypt_ctx_size,
   crypt_ctx_init,
   crypt_ctx_update,
   crypt_ctx_finish,
   encrypted_length
};


class Parser {
public:
   Parser(const std::string& filename, const std::string& filekey)
       : m_filename(filename), m_filekey(filekey) {
       // Additional initialization if needed
   }


   int parse(std::map<unsigned int, KeyEntry>* keys) {
       readKeyFile(m_filename); // Call to read the key file
       return 0;
   }


private:
   std::string m_filename;
   std::string m_filekey;
};


static int fileKeyManagementPluginInit(void *p) {`your text`
   Parser parser(filename, filekey);
   return parser.parse(&keys);
}
static int fileKeyManagementPluginDeinit(void *p) {
   keys.clear();
   return 0;
}
int _mysql_plugin_interface_version_ = MARIA_PLUGIN_INTERFACE_VERSION;
struct st_mysql_plugin _mysql_plugin_declarations_[] = {
   {
       MariaDB_ENCRYPTION_PLUGIN,
       &JISA_Enc_plugin,
       "JISA_Encryption_Plugin",
       "JISA-Softech",
       "User key management plugin",
       PLUGIN_LICENSE_GPL,
       fileKeyManagementPluginInit,
       fileKeyManagementPluginDeinit,
       0x0100 /* 1.0 */,
       nullptr, /* status variables */
       settings,
       nullptr,
       MariaDB_PLUGIN_MATURITY_STABLE
   },
   {0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0}
};


maria_declare_plugin(JISA_Enc_plugin) {
   MariaDB_ENCRYPTION_PLUGIN,
   &JISA_Enc_plugin,
   "JISA_Encryption_Plugin",
   "JISA-Softech",
   "User key management plugin",
   PLUGIN_LICENSE_GPL,
   fileKeyManagementPluginInit,
   fileKeyManagementPluginDeinit,
   0x0100 /* 1.0 */,
   NULL, /* status variables */
   settings,
   "1.0",
   MariaDB_PLUGIN_MATURITY_STABLE
}
maria_declare_plugin_end;


Mariadb is not mysql. Did you check if your code complies with mariadb plugin development criteria?

This code would not run as a mysql plugin with all the mariadb specific constants and structs.
